# CEDET Cache Error

Tags: emacs, cedet

When emacs starts up, CEDET complains about a series of cache files being write protected:

> Cache Error:
>   [~/.semanticdb/!usr!include!i386-linux-gnu!sys!semantic.cache]
>   (error In save file, list of object constructors found, but no :type
>   specified for slot :tables), Restart Note: file is write protected [2
>   times]

And when I call `semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu` for the first time, a load of cache errors are thrown and the minibuffer goes crazy with error messages for a few seconds.

> Cache Error:
>   [~/.semanticdb/!usr!include!i386-linux-gnu!gnu!semantic.cache]
>   (error In save file, list of object constructors found, but no :type
>   specified for slot :tables), Restart [8 times]

After the initial call, the problems go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit emacs, remove `~/.semanticdb` & start again - the directory will be recreated & files will be reparsed. It looks like, you run emacs as root.

Or you can simply change permissions with `chown -R <your id> ~/.semanticdb` and `chmod -R a-w,u+wr ~/.semanticdb`